# JWT issue when I try to authenticate a Github app

Tags: github, jwt, github-api

I'm trying to authenticate a Github app. I generated the JWT using Ruby script provided [here](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authentication-options-for-github-apps/#jwt-payload).

I then ran this curl script as instructed:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_JWT" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json" https://api.github.com/app
```

I placed my JWT in the necessary place but it didn't work. I get a 401 response with the following message:

> A JSON web token could not be decoded

Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Ruby script:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'jwt'  # https://rubygems.org/gems/jwt

# Private key contents
private_pem = File.read(YOUR_PATH_TO_PEM)
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(private_pem)

# Generate the JWT
payload = {
  # issued at time
  iat: Time.now.to_i,
  # JWT expiration time (10 minute maximum)
  exp: Time.now.to_i + (10 * 60),
  # GitHub App's identifier
  iss: YOUR_ISSUE_NUMBER
}

jwt = JWT.encode(payload, private_key, "RS256")
puts jwt
```

It worked when I ncluded the YOUR_ISSUE_NUMBER in quotes. E.g. `iss: "1234"`.